# Edge finding with Numpy

Tags: numpy, image-processing

Find edges with NumPy 1D search in stencil like b&w image, e.g. [image: img]

Not sure how to loop through 1D arrays to create a bool mask properly. Looked through quite a few numpy resources & stack which didn't cover explicitly this kind of basic operation.

Any tips appreciated.
Here's the pseudocode.

```
#Pseudocode for 1D array search.
nrows, ncols = img.shape[:2]
nrows = nrows-1     #avoid index error
ncols = ncols-1

    # i+1 pixel index wanted here
outedges_row = (img[nrows][i] == 0) & (img[nrows][i+1] == 255)  
outedges_col = (img[ncols][i] == 0) & (img[ncols][i+1] == 255)

    # i pixel index wanted here
inedges_row = (img[nrows][i] == 255) & (img[nrows][i+1] == 0)
inedges_col = (img[ncols][i] == 255) & (img[ncols][i+1] == 0)

    # display outline of shapes
edges = np.unique(outedges_row & outedges_col & inedges_col & inedges_row)
img2 = np.copy(img)
img2[edges]
cv.imshow('',img2)
```

Even a very simple outline of the shape would be very valuable learning for my purposes.

Edit: Expected output
[image]

Comment: What outlines are you expecting ? Show us.

Answer (score 2):

An "edge" pixel is characterized by a simple property: it is black and at least one of its neighbors is white (you can choose between the 4- or 8- connected neighbors).

This is fairly simple to implement. On the sides of the image, consider that "outer" pixels are white.

Answer (score 0):

The typical method for edge detection is to take a "derivative" or to convolve with an "edge detection kernel" (e.g. Sobel, Laplacian of Gaussian, ...).

For instance, this gives a very simple horizontal derivative:

```
# kernel: (-1, 1)
dx = img[:, 1:] - img[:, :-1]
```

Second order operator:

```
# kernel: (-1, 2, -1)
dx = -img[:, 2:] + 2 * img[:, 1:-1] - img[:, :-2]
```

...which incidentally creates a map of all the vertical edges.

To convert to a boolean map, one may follow up with a thresholding operation on the result:

```
edge = dx > THRESHOLD
```

Typical Laplacian of Gaussian kernel:

```
edge = (
    0 * img[:-2, :-2]  + -1 * img[:-2, 1:-1]  +  0 * img[:-2, 2:]  +
   -1 * img[1:-1, :-2] +  4 * img[1:-1, 1:-1] + -1 * img[1:-1, 2:] +
    0 * img[2:, :-2]   + -1 * img[2:, 1:-1]   +  0 * img[2:, 2:]  
)
```

If you're not restricted to linear operators, you can even do stuff like `edges = abs(dx) + abs(dy)`... just be careful of phase shifts.

---

Another "non-linear" method as suggested by @Yves is to use 4-connected neighbors. One possible implementation:

```
img = (img >= 128).astype(np.uint8)
img_p = np.pad(img, 1, mode='edge')

connectivity = (
    0 * img_p[ :-2, :-2] +  1 * img_p[ :-2, 1:-1] +  0 * img_p[ :-2, 2:] +
    1 * img_p[1:-1, :-2] +  0 * img_p[1:-1, 1:-1] +  1 * img_p[1:-1, 2:] +
    0 * img_p[2:,   :-2] +  1 * img_p[2:,   1:-1] +  0 * img_p[2:,   2:]
)

edge = (img == 1) & (connectivity >= 1) & (connectivity < 4)
```

Comment: The image is black & white.

Comment: I'm confused by how to use this method in a 1D 'loop' with conditions, e.g. to show the border extrema. Are you able to / feel like sharing an example of this? Ty

Comment: You don’t use Sobel to detect edges in a binary image. And you never use a Laplacian to detect edges (unless you follow it up with a zero crossing detector).

Comment: @YvesDaoust If that is an issue, couldn't one just convert to a data type with more levels, though?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: you can indeed lowpass the image before applying a derivative filter. But in the end edge detection is made on whole pixels, so back to binary with non-maxima suppression. What do you gain with this added complexity ? Just that you are no more sure to obtain a connected curve.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq by border extrema I meant getting outline of furthest pixels from center with 1D search. It was not explicit in the question.You found another solution. Still seeking help with simple implementation of 1D search "loop" toward this end, as this was main intent of post. Thanks & sorry for not being crystal clear.

Comment: @user014162314 Sounds like you may want a flood-fill. I'm not sure what you mean by looping through a 1D array, but `img.reshape(-1)` flattens any array into 1D.